# What does the command ls -L do?

Tags: linux, ls

What does the command `ls -L` do in ubuntu and what are some use cases for it? Examples would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the man page:

```
   -L, --dereference
          when showing file information for a symbolic link, show
          information for the file the link references rather than for
          the link itself
```

Try specifying a symbolic link as argument to `ls` with and without the `-L` flag to see the difference.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to add some more insight into the nature of symbolic links as the OP clearly seems to be a novice on that part, and may not fully understand your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

it dereferences symbolic links, and shows what it is pointed to instead. For example:

```
user@mysystem:~/u&l$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=example.img bs=1024 count=0  seek=$[1024*10]
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000104833 s, 0.0 kB/s
user@mysystem:~/u&l$ ln -s example.img ex

user@mysystem:~/u&l$ ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  11 Sep  9 01:07 ex -> example.img
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10M Sep  9 01:06 example.img

user@mysystem:~/u&l$ ls -lhL
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10M Sep  9 01:06 ex
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10M Sep  9 01:06 example.img
user@mysystem:~/u&l$
```

Notice without the L, you see that ex is a symbolic link  indicating where it is linked to, also notice the file size differences, and the lowercase l denoting it is a symlink.  Notice with the -L option set, we no longer can discern it from the file it is linked to from the listing.  In a way it like a ls would if you used a hardlink instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` options dereferences symbolic links. To see what it practically means, lets create a directory and symbolic link to it, and check inode numbers:

```
$ mkdir dir1
$ ln -s dir1/ dir2
$ ls -li
total 2
6030486 drwxr-xr-x 2 merlin merlin 4096 Sep  9 07:46 dir1
6030487 lrwxrwxrwx 1 merlin merlin    5 Sep  9 07:47 dir2 -> dir1/
```

Then, add `-L` to the `ls` call:

```
$ ls -Lli
total 2
6030486 drwxr-xr-x 2 merlin merlin 4096 Sep  9 07:46 dir1
6030486 drwxr-xr-x 2 merlin merlin 4096 Sep  9 07:46 dir2
```

You can see that the inode numbers printed in the first column are different. File size, permissions is also different, they show attributes of `dir1` directory, not symbolic link `dir2`.